# Pure CSS3 Vertical Accordion

Tags: css, accordion

I am having trouble figuring out a way to keep the tab open when a header is selected. 
Currently the tab will only stay open when the mouse is hovering over, but as soon as the mouse is moved into another area, the tab closes. Thank you

```
 }


.verticalaccordion>ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style:none;
    width: 280px;
    float: right;

}

.verticalaccordion>ul>li {
    display:block;
    overflow: hidden;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style:none;
    height:40px;
    width: 280px;

    /* Decorative CSS */
    background-color:#f0f0f0;


}

.verticalaccordion>ul>li>h3 {
    display:block;
    margin: 0;
    padding:10px;
    height:19px;

    /* Decorative CSS */
    border-top:#f0f0f0 1px solid;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;

    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #074377;


}

.verticalaccordion>ul>li>div {
    margin:0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding:10px;
    height:220px;

}

.verticalaccordion>ul>li:hover {
    height: 280px;
}

.verticalaccordion:hover>ul>li:hover>h3 {
    /* Decorative CSS */
    color:#fff;
    background: #CA006C;
}   




    verticalaccordion section:target  
    {  
        width: 30em;  
        padding: 0 1em;  
        color: #333;  
        background-color: #fff;  
    }  
    verticalaccordion section:target h2  
    {  
        position: static;  
        font-size: 1.3em;  
        text-indent: 0;  
        color: #333;  
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);  
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);  
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);  
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);  
        transform: rotate(0deg);  
    }
```

Here is a sample of the rest of the code:

```
        <div id="google-map">
<iframe src="frame link" name="frame" width="550" marginwidth="0" height="650" marginheight="0" scrolling="No" frameborder="0" id="frame-window"></iframe></div><div class="verticalaccordion" >

  <ul>
    <li>
      <h3>Menu</h3>
      <div>
        <ul class="location">
          <li><a href="Link" target="frame">Link 1</a><br />
            <font color="#000000">Link Info</font></li>
          <li><a href="Link 2" target="frame">Link 2</a><br />
            <font color="#000000"> Link Info</font>    </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to have the drop down menu stay open, even when the mouse is no longer hovering, until another category is selected

Answer (score 4):

Check this demo I've made a while ago http://dabblet.com/gist/1728264 - I think it does exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks Ana! I tried out your code in IE7 & IE8, wherein it broke. I know the Target Selector is not compatible in both IE7-8, but I would like to insert it into the script for more advance browsers, but I'm unsure where in the script & how to place the tag. Thanks!

Comment: My demo works in IE8 & IE9, though without the transition. There is a problem with IE7, where you have to hover off the panel before it opens. It also does not use :target or any kind of JavaScript. To help with integration I would need to see your HTML first.